# Using the definition of limit show that

Tags: limits

USING THE DEFINITION:

For any $ε > 0$ , there is  $δ > 0$ ;
   $| x - a | < δ$
Then $| F(x) - L | < ε$

SHOW THAT:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -2}(\frac{-x}{2}-4)=-3$$

Comment: Please share what you have done.

Comment: And what else? What have you tried?

Comment: Start by letting Epsilon$>0$ and assuming $|x+2|<$delta.

Comment: | F(x) - L | < ε 
| ( -x/2 -4 ) + 3 | < ε 
| ( -x/2 + 1 ) | < ε
| ( -X + 2 / 2 | < ε
| ( -X + 2 ) | < 2ε

Now I just want to remove the " -" before " X" but how?

Comment: One sec I got you with a proof

Comment: I need to get to |x+2|
but now I am stuck here  |  -X + 2  |

Comment: Isn't $-x/2-4+3=-x/2-1$ and not $-x/2+1$?

Comment: thanks for help, I found the solution.

Comment: With absolute value you can factor out negatives, if this helped please upvote and accept as answer.:]

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=-\frac{x}2-4$$

The goal is to find $\delta$ such that $\delta > \lvert x-(-2)\rvert > 0 \implies \exists\epsilon>0,\,\epsilon > \lvert f(x)-(-3) \rvert$

Start with $\epsilon$ and use that to define $\delta$:

$$\epsilon > \lvert f(x)-(-3) \rvert>0$$
$$\epsilon > \lvert (-\frac{x}2-4)+3 \rvert>0$$
$$\epsilon > \lvert -\frac{x}2-1 \rvert>0$$
$$\epsilon > \lvert-\frac12\rvert\cdot\lvert x+2\rvert>0$$
$$\epsilon > \frac12\lvert x+2\rvert>0$$
$$2\epsilon > \lvert x-(-2)\rvert>0$$

Now, simply define $\delta=2\epsilon$ and the proof is complete. In order to verify this, simply work through the above steps in reverse.